# Write array results to string using Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have to loop through `fval` and write the corresponding text value as comma separated string like `val1,val1,val3`, further description is provided below.

```
fval = "[12, 2, 7]"
```

Each value in `fval` is having corresponding text values like

```
id : "12" = "val1"
id : "7"  = "val2"
id : "2"  = "val3"
```

The code I have written is stuck at splitting `fval` and storing them into array.

```
Dim arry() As String

arry() = Split(Mid(fval, 2, Len(fval) - 2), ", ")

For x = LBound(arry) To UBound(arry)
    If id = arry(x) Then          

    End If
Next
```

Should I make an another array to store the returning values to write? Or is there any other workarounds.

Comment: I guess these mixed `"` and `'` are just typos in `fval = ["12', "7', "2"]`? You should correct them if so.

Comment: what is `fval` a string?

Comment: yes, favl is string. i have made the changes.

Comment: what if you put this in 2 lines instead (find Mid THEN Split):  `arry() = Split(Mid(fval, 2, Len(fval) - 2), ", ")`?

Comment: you can declare a string(Ex: strng) variable and make it null at start. then inside the loop {strng=strng & strng_value_for_the_id & ","} then you are left with a , at the end which you can leave out at the last. So you are  left with a single string.

Comment: Yep, That worked. i'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sivaprasath V mentioned concatenating the values works

```
Dim arry() As String

arry() = Split(Mid(fval, 2, Len(fval) - 2), ", ")

For x = LBound(arry) To UBound(arry)
    If id = arry(x) Then          
        If fieldVal <> "" Then
           fieldVal = fieldVal & ", " & id
        Else
           fieldVal = id
        End If
    End If
Next
```

By end of the loop `fieldVal = val1,val1,val3`